# How to orient listbox horizontally ? [XUL/Firefox]

Tags: javascript, firefox, listbox, firefox-addon, xul

Firefox add-on. For some reasons, I wish to orient [listbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/listbox) entries horizontally. By default they are oriented vertically. For eg: I have this code

```
<listbox id="myList">
  <listitem label="A"/>
  <listitem label="B"/>
  <listitem label="C" selected="true"/>
</listbox>
```

- `orient` attribute doesn't work on the `listbox` element
- I can orient the elements horizontally if I wrap the `listitem`s in an `hbox`. But that is not a standard approach and would result in wrong `selectedIndex` etc.
- I experimented with `richlistbox` as well, but doesn't help.

So is there a way to orient listbox elements horizontally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the approach you suggested (hbox) renders the `selectedIndex` property unusable but `selectedItem` still works!

```
<listbox id="myList" onselect="(this.selectedItem.label='x')">
  <hbox style="">
    <listitem label="Aaa"/>
    <listitem label="Bbbb"/>
    <listitem label="Ccccc"/>
  </hbox>
</listbox>
```

Or how about using a toolbar:

```
<toolbar style="-moz-appearance:groupbox" flex="0">
  <toolbarbutton type="radio" group="xxx" label="a"/>
  <toolbarbutton type="radio" group="xxx" label="b"/>
  <toolbarbutton type="radio" group="xxx" label="c"/>
</toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you! Although setting a property on `selectedItem` works, I cannot somehow read an attribute. For eg: `onselect="(someElement.label = this.selectedItem.label)"`. That gives me an `undefined`. Very strange. But thanks for the `toolbar` solution. I think that is a much better approach in my case - Although I wanted a listitem which can be easily styled and would look consistent. But I'll experiement and get back.

Comment: So I couldn't get that `selectedItem` to work, and toolbar solution wasn't really of my taste. I ended up writing one with `hbox`es and some click event listeners! Thanks for your solutions though. It might help someone else.